# using void methods in log method

Tags: android, android-logcat, return-type

In `MainActivity` class:

```
Log.i("Game ends! ","" + object1.winner()+ object2.winner());
```

In `Game` class:

```
public void winner() {
    if(this.points!=0) {
        Log.i("Winner is", this.objectName);
    }
}
```

Error is: '+ operator can no be applied to java.lang.String,void

As per the expertise of the given answers users I have done this.

```
public String winner() {
    if(this.points!=0) {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

error: missing return statement

Comment: The solution is fairly simple. Do **not** log anything in the `gettermethod()`, instead return what should be printed, and use that return value like `Log.i("Number stored in a given object","" + object.gettermethod());`

Comment: You said, **But then I need to return something! and whatever I return (0/ etc) it is also getting printed in Log catalog which I don't want. What to do?** If you don't want to print anything then just don't concat it to log.

Comment: or simply create getter method with return type String and return "";(**Empty String**)

Comment: ^ That would be silly

Comment: Are you perhaps unaware that you can just have `object.gettermethod() ;` as a statement to invoke a method when you don't care about its return? The method can then happily be declared as returning `void` (and, log its own messages to logcat if needed).

Comment: @TimCastelijns I edited and showing what I am trying to do

Comment: @user6177394 my first comment still applies

Comment: @Why is it saying missing return statement? & If this is a very noob question should I delete it?

Comment: @it is solved now, I didn't put 'else' statement as the other answerer pointed out. 
Thank your for your time. ( I know I shouldn't be thanking ) but after getting -6 it's worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `void` keyword is not an object or a variable, all it does is specify that a method does not return anything. So the following line means that the function will return `void` (i.e. nothing):

```
public void doSomething() {}
```

Therefore, using the method `Log.i()` to print *nothing* is not possible. This method expects two `String` objects, which it can print to the logcat. The only reason you can use an `int` is because of the way Java handles `String` concatenation; it automatically converts any primitive type (`boolean`, `int`, `float`, etc.) to a `String` when using the `+` operator.

---

The reason the `Log` methods expects *two* `String` objects is simply to maintain legibility in logcat. The first parameter is meant to be a `TAG` variable, which is usually the name of the `Class` that is calling the method. This is usually done by creating a static value in each class:

```
private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

In this way, you can use the `Log` methods as follows:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Log information…");
```

Which will result in a more uniform message written to logcat.

---

So, with this information, the question remains; what are you trying to output to logcat?

If you just want to output that the method was called, than simply call the `Log` statement before (or after) the method call:

```
Log.i(TAG, "doSomething() called");
doSomething();
```

Otherwise, if you actually expect your method to `return` a printable result, then you must return something other than `void`. Either a `String`, a primitive type, or an `Object` that can be printed using the `toString()` method.

Comment: I have edited the question to show what I was really trying to do.

Comment: @user6177394, your edit has no impact on my answer. The error message you are seeing is stating that you cannot concatenate `void`; your methods must `return` *something* if you expect them to print something.

Comment: did what you say. Missing return statement when using String.

Comment: why is it saying missing return statement?

Comment: @user6177394 I am assuming you changed the `void` to another type (`int`, `String`, etc.); in this case you need to call `return` [`int`, `String`, etc.] to tell the method what to return when called. I recommend you review some [Java training](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) in order to get a handle on how functions work.

Comment: I am trying to return object.name which is of String type. Why I am having return statement error

Comment: Ah, your `winner()` function also includes an `if` statement. If the function has a type other than `void` (in this case `String`), it *must* return something. If your `if` statement evaluates to `false` the `return` statement is skipped, resulting in an error. Therefore, you should add an `else` statement, in which case you can either `return` some other `String`, an empty `String` (`""`) or `null`.

Comment: OMG! yes!. it was this 'if' statement causing all the trouble.
I know i shouldn't be thanking in comments. But thank you so much! :)